# need to get the information of newly getting dragged object information in angular js ui tree

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-tree

In Angular js ui-tree ([ui-tree](http://ngmodules.org/modules/angular-ui-tree)), how can I get the newly dragged object information? I am getting tree left side list and right side list without any problem but I am facing problem to get model value of the newly getting dragged object only. Let say, I have 4 objects on the right side list, now I am dragging another item from left list and dropping on right side list, now I want only that 5th dragged item information, Is there any simple way to get that information?

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

dropped(event)

If a node moves it's position after dropped, the nodeDropped callback will be called.

In the html : `<div ui-tree="treeOptions">`

In the JS:

```
myAppModule.controller('MyController', function($scope) {    
  $scope.treeOptions = {
    dropped: function(event) {
      // what ever you want.    
    }
  };    
});
```